# how to increment a date in a linux shell when the date is a variable

Tags: shell, date

I need to keep incrementing a date variable by 15 minutes. 
This script increments the current date

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0,15,30,45}
do
  date --date='+'$i' minutes' +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
  echo "$date"
done
```

But I need to set the initial date for a year ago and keep incrementing for a span of a year.
Is it possible to create a datetime variable and keep adding minutes to it in a loop?

I need this to download files named like 20190101231500.csv and every next filename has a timestamp of 15 min later.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With minimal change to your code :

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in {0,15,30,45}
do
  date --date="-$i minutes ago" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
  echo "$date"
done`
```

you can use the option `X months/days/years/minutes ago` with `--date` to subtract from the current date. Use negative numbers to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Using `date --date` for calculating a lot of dates will become very slow.

```
# With date calculations (too) slow, only done for 10 days
d="2015-01-01"
((maxminutes=24*60))
while [ "$d" != "2015-01-10" ]; do
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
  for ((m=0; m<${maxminutes};m+=15)); do
     date -d "${d} + ${m} minutes" +"%Y%m%d%H%M"
  done
done
```

An alternative is using awk, preventing calling another program so often

```
awk -v startdate="2015-01-01" -v enddate="2015-01-10" 'BEGIN {
         printf("%s %s\n", startdate, enddate);
      split(startdate,A,"[-]");
      T1=mktime(A[1] " " A[2] " " A[3] " 0 0 0");
      split(enddate,B,"[-]");
      T2=mktime(B[1] " " B[2] " " B[3] " 23 59 59");
      while (T1 < T2) {
         printf("%s\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",T1));
         T1+=60*15;
      }
   }'
```

Comment: Thank you Walter! I choose the first solution although I like the second as well. Would be nice to be able to specify the time start and time end as well in addition to date but not important for me know.

Comment: I do not understand your time start wish (just add a call to `date`?). Did you know the special variable SECONDS? Try: `echo "${SECONDS}"; sleep 14; echo "${SECONDS}"`? Or use time command like `time while .... done > /dev/null` and `time awk ... }' > /dev/null` and see the difference!